# How to calculate how many "double-downs" can be done given a total balance and a starting bid

Tags: problem-solving, constraints, gambling

I want to know how can this be calculated mathematically.

Given a total balance $\mathrm{B}$ and an initial bet of $\mathrm{b_{init}}$, I want to calculate the max number of double-downs ($\mathrm{X}$) I can do before I get to $\mathrm{B}$ (i.e. max possible value being strictly lower than $\mathrm{B}$). The total bid quantity by doing consecutive double-downs is calculated as follows:
$$
\sum_{x=0}^{X} 2^x \times \mathrm{b_{init}}
$$

For example, given a total balance $\mathrm{B}=150000$ an initial bet of $\mathrm{b_{init}}=100$, the result value ($\mathrm{X}$) should be $\mathrm{X} = 9$, because $ \sum_{x=0}^{9} 2^x \times \mathrm{100} = 102300 < \mathrm{B} $, but $ \sum_{x=0}^{10} 2^x \times \mathrm{100} = 204700 > \mathrm{B} $

Comment: What is a "double-down" and in which game is it present ?

Comment: Double-down is to double your bet, normally when losing your bet in the hope of winning the next one and recovering your loss. An example of this successive action is present in the Martingale method (used long time ago in the roulette)

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now ("doubler la mise" in French ; maybe a similar expression in Spanish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the largest $X$ such that $$\sum_{x=0}^{X}2^x\times b_{init}<B$$
But the left side quantity is a sum of $X+1$ terms of a geometric progression with ratio $2$ and first term $b_{init}$. So using the standard formula we write:
$$(2^{X+1}-1)\times b_{init}<B\iff X<\log_2\left(\frac{B}{b_{init}}+1\right)-1$$
Thus using the greatest integer function, we can state our answer as:
$$X_{max}=\left\lfloor\log_2\left(\frac{B}{b_{init}}+1\right)\right\rfloor-1$$
If $B>b_{init}$, we can check that $X_{max}$ is always non-negative.